# bigquery actions are execute asynchronously, how about storage actions?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics

```
function upload_object($bucketName, $objectName, $source)
{
  $storage = new StorageClient();
  $file = fopen($source, 'r');
  $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
  $object = $bucket->upload($file, [
    'name' => $objectName
  ]);
  printf('Uploaded %s to gs://%s/%s' . PHP_EOL, basename($source), 
  $bucketName, $objectName);
}
```

Comparing with bigquery actions, due to most bigquery actions take long time to finish, they are executed asynchronously. see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs

Such as when we use bigquery client to export data to storage.

Now when we use storage client to load data,

My question is about the storage statement

```
$object = $bucket->upload($file, [
  'name' => $objectName
]);
```

Is this statement executed asynchronously? due to the document does not show it is executed asynchronously, I will assume it is not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to an API being synchronous - the service itself and your client library. The BigQuery service is asynchronous as it returns an "operation" token and you must poll to see when that operation is complete. The GCS service is synchronous as when the upload API call completes (or the final call of a resumable upload) the object is then in place.

However even with a synchronous service, you might have a *client library* that is aysnchronus as it could do the uploading in a background thread while your code continues with some kind of promise or future object. The [PHP client library upload method is synchronous, however](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.36.0/storage/bucket?method=upload).

**TL;DR: In PHP uploading to GCS is synchronous. After the call is complete, your object is in place.**